# how to write a query to count number of reservations that have been placed by sourcing DSV and OWN

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table RESERVATIONS having columns like ReservationID, SOURCING.

Sample Data:

```
ReservationKey  ReservationID   ItemID  Sourcing
1                123            Item1   DSV
2                123            Item2   OWN
3                456            Item3   DSV
4                456            Item4   OWN
5                789            Item1   DSV
6                789            Item3   DSV
7                789            Item4   OWN
8               1000            Item2   OWN
```

Result:

```
Reservations ReservedItems
3            7
```

I need to count the total number of reservations having Sourcing both DSV and OWN.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps:

```
select count(*)
from (select ReservationID
      from reservations
      where Sourcing in ('DSV', 'OWN')
      group by ReservationID
      having min(Sourcing) <> max(sourcing)
     ) x;
```

You can actually do this without a subquery in the `from` clause . . . but I think a subquery is still necessary:

```
select count(distinct r.ReservationID)
from reservations r
where r.Sourcing = 'DSV' and
      exists (select 1
              from reservations r r2
              where r2.ReservationID = r.ReservationID and r2.Sourcing = 'OWN'
             );
```